# MetaTrader (MQL4) > .DLL (Delphi/Pascal) > .jar (Java) | Java-Thread seems to close immediately when opened via .dll (ShellExecute) via mql-call

Tags: java, dll, pascal, mql4, metatrader4

(I use Windows 11 Home) To establish a communication between MetaTrader4 and my own Java Application I want to use stdin and stdout pipes. At this moment, I try to open my .jar from a .dll called by mql.

But when I start my MQL Expert, import the dll (successful), I only get a blink of an eye console window. Also I cant find a matching thread in taskmanager

My Java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class SystemOutTest {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
          JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Window");
          JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello, World!");
          frame.add(label);
          frame.setSize(200, 100);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          
          Thread.sleep(9000);
       }
}
```

My .dll:

```
library JarLauncher;

uses
    Windows, ShellAPI;

function LaunchJar(const AFileName: string; const AArguments: string): Integer; stdcall;

    var
    JavaPath: string;

    begin
        JavaPath := 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_361\bin\java.exe';
        Result := ShellExecute(
            0,
            nil,
            'java.exe',
            '-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar testpilot.jar',
            nil,
            SW_SHOW
        );
    end;

exports
    LaunchJar;

begin
end.
```

And my MQL:

```
#import "JarLauncher.dll"
int LaunchJar(string AFileName, string AArguments);
#import

void OnInit()
{
   // string jarFile = "C:\\path\\to\\testpilot.jar";
   string jarFile = "testpilot.jar";
   string arguments = "";
   
   int result = LaunchJar(jarFile, arguments);
   if (result <= 0)
   {
      Print("Failed to launch JAR file!");
   }
   else
   {
      Print(result);
   }
   Sleep(9000);
}
```

I know MT4 is 32Bit, so I got my Lazarus and Eclipse and JRE to 32Bit.
I get no Errors.
Got through some trouble there (ERR 126, file not found), so I am confident, that my MQL finds the dll and executes fine.

My Output in MT4 Console is:

```
2023.04.15 20:43:28.558    maybeload [DJI30],H1: 42
2023.04.15 20:43:26.064    Expert maybeload [DJI30],H1: loaded successfully
```

I think 42 is no Error Code but a Process Handle?

In my dll I played around with ShellExcecute with different Variations of java.exe and full path and javaw.exe and -jar argument and also SW_SHOWNORMAL and SW_SHOWDEFAULT and SW_SHOW. Nothing changed a bit.

I can start my .jar from cmd and from explorer (doubleclick) without Problems and see the window.

I couldnot run it via rundll32, probably because I messed up the command.

I figured it could be some problem with MQL Thread Handling... but im stuck since days now.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to assume that Pascal string = Java string.  They are not the same.

Rewrite the interface to use pchar in Pascal and and read up on JNI options in Java to interface to (char *)   Probably char[].